# Trouble rendering XML data to div (and possibly selecting right XML nodes)

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, xml, sharepoint

I'm trying to take XML data and render it into a div, `specifically the Label and Title nodes`.

Ideally it'll look something like this:

```
<div class="col-md-3" id="middle-id">
  <[Templates]> // xml data taken from d:Label node
</div>
```

I think the error lies with the syntax for selecting the right nodes, but I'm not that familiar with XML and node selection so I can't say for sure.

Any thoughts? Help would be much appreciated.

#### Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://[website].com/[]/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Documents List')/items?$top=1000&$select=Title,ResourceType",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {

      // parse xml file and get data
      let xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml),
        $xml = $(xmlDoc);
      $xml.find('d:Label').each(function() { // the syntax of only ('d:Label') doesn't seem right to me
        $('#middle-id').append($(this).text() + "<br />");
      });
    }
  });
</script>
```

#### Section of XML

```
<entry m:etag="&quot;4&quot;">
... // other stuff is here
    <content type="application/xml">
        <m:properties>
            <d:Title m:null="true" />
            <d:ResourceType m:type="Collection([SP field value])">
                <d:element>
                    <d:Label>Templates</d:Label>
                    <d:TermGuid>[guid]</d:TermGuid>
                    <d:WssId m:type="[stuff]">941</d:WssId>
                </d:element>
            </d:ResourceType>
        </m:properties>
    </content>
</entry>
```

#### HTML

```
<div class="col-md-3" id="middle-id"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got a couple problems. First of all, don't try parsing the XML string and then convert it to a jQuery object. Just put convert the XML string directly to a jQuery object. Secondly, the colon character needs to be escaped with two backslashes when used as a jQuery selector.

If you change your JavaScript to the below, it should work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://[website].com/[]/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Documents List')/items?$top=1000&$select=Title,ResourceType",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {

      // parse xml file and get data
      let $xml = $(xml);
      $xml.find('d\\:Label').each(function() {
        $('#middle-id').append($(this).text() + "<br />");
      });
    }
  });
</script>
```

Here's a working example of how the whole thing would work (minus the ajax call):

```js
let xml = '<entry m:etag="&quot;4&quot;"><content type="application/xml"><m:properties><d:Title m:null="true" /><d:ResourceType m:type="Collection([SP field value])"><d:element><d:Label>Templates</d:Label><d:TermGuid>[guid]</d:TermGuid><d:WssId m:type="[stuff]">941</d:WssId></d:element></d:ResourceType></m:properties></content></entry>';

let $xml = $(xml);
$xml.find('d\\:Label').each(function() {
  $('#middle-id').append($(this).text() + "<br />");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-3" id="middle-id"></div>
```

Comment: Good call on escaping and the : . I will definitely make that change. As for the `let xml=entry... etc,` the full length of the xml data (from the URL) is over 10k lines long. How would I update the `let xml...` line to accommodate that?

Comment: I'm not suggesting you hardcode the xml on your page, that was just there as a code sample. I updated the answer for clarity.

Comment: Nothing yet, I'm afraid. I'll switch things around and see what I can do. :\

Comment: What is the issue now? Where is it failing? Does the `find()` get called and not return anything?

Comment: Hi dave, I ended up converting the XML file to JSON (http://jsonprettyprint.com/) and was able to get the data to render from there.